# Display multiple directions in Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display multiple directions in a single map. In the code below I've tried to declare two of them but Google display one single path that include all points. How can I separate them? Also, can I set a different colour for each direction?

PS: I've searched StackOverflow but I've found solutions only for older API versions.

```
<script>
    function initMap() {

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var map;

        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(46.499729, 26.647089);
        var mapOrigin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.596652, 26.812765);
        var mapDestination1 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.4674824,26.4513263);
        var mapOrigin2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.5476592,26.515106);
        var mapDestination2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.4444641,27.362008);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: mapCenter
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        function calculateRoute(mapOrigin, mapDestination) {
            var request = {
                origin: mapOrigin,
                destination: mapDestination,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == "OK") {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });   
        }
        calculateRoute(mapOrigin1, mapDestination1);
        calculateRoute(mapOrigin2, mapDestination2);

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display multiple routes on the map, you need multiple `DirectionRenderer` objects.

related question: [Google Maps API : multiple direction/route on same map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679965/google-maps-api-multiple-direction-route-on-same-map)

Simplest fix, create a new `DirectionsRenderer`object each time you call the `calculateRoute` function (if you need to change the routes or hide them later, you will need to keep references to these `DirectionRenderer1 objects).

```
function calculateRoute(mapOrigin, mapDestination) {
    var request = {
        origin: mapOrigin,
        destination: mapDestination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == "OK") {
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map:map});
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });   
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/61a93ove/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var map;

  var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(46.499729, 26.647089);
  var mapOrigin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.596652, 26.812765);
  var mapDestination1 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.4674824, 26.4513263);
  var mapOrigin2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.5476592, 26.515106);
  var mapDestination2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.4444641, 27.362008);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: mapCenter
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  function calculateRoute(mapOrigin, mapDestination) {
    var request = {
      origin: mapOrigin,
      destination: mapDestination,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
      if (status == "OK") {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          map: map
        });
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      }
    });
  }
  calculateRoute(mapOrigin1, mapDestination1);
  calculateRoute(mapOrigin2, mapDestination2);

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use separate `DirectionsRenderer` objects (one for each route).

```js
function initMap() {

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(46.499729, 26.647089);
  var mapOrigin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.596652, 26.812765);
  var mapDestination1 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.4674824, 26.4513263);
  var mapOrigin2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.5476592, 26.515106);
  var mapDestination2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.4444641, 27.362008);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: mapCenter
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  function calculateRoute(mapOrigin, mapDestination) {
  
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    });
    
    var request = {
      origin: mapOrigin,
      destination: mapDestination,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };
    
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
      if (status == "OK") {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      }
    });
  }
  
  calculateRoute(mapOrigin1, mapDestination1);
  calculateRoute(mapOrigin2, mapDestination2);
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```